# Why does the typeof a numerical array index in a "for..in" loop considered a string?

Tags: javascript, typeof, for-in-loop, array-key

I noticed that in Javascript a variable used as the index in a `for..in` loop will be always a `string` even if I define it the following way:

```
var s_array = new Array();
s_array[0] = 'foo';
s_array[1] = 'bar';

for(i in s_array){
 alert(typeof(i)); // String
}
```

Why is it considered a `string` and not a `number`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `for(x in y)` syntax is intended to iterate over the properties of an object (*not the indexes of an array*), and property names are always stored as strings.

The fact that it also works for arrays is a side effect of array elements being properties on the array object.

To understand the difference, consider this code:

```
var s_array = new Array();
s_array[0] = 'foo';
s_array[1] = 'bar';
s_array['foo'] = 'bar';

console.log("Object:");
for(i in s_array) {
 console.log(i);   
}
console.log("Array:");
for(var i = 0, l = s_array.length; i < l; i++) {
 console.log(i);   
}
```

which provides the following output:

```
Object:
0
1
foo
Array:
0
1
```

There's a `foo` property on the object, but it's not actually an element inside the array.

Comment: I find your wording slightly confusing: array indexes are not "mapped" to properties, array elements _are_ properties. Arrays are just like other objects, there's nothing special about them.

Comment: @thg435 Good point, edited. I was trying to indicate that there's a slight difference between array elements as properties and other properties set on the object, but definitely could have worded it better.

Comment: first thank you all for the answers, so when I am asking for s_array[1] behind the scene.. there is some conversion of the number 1 to string?

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are essentially objects with managed set of indexed keys.

Since every key in an object is of type string hence it is a string as well.

Consider your array as :

```
{"0" : "foo" , "1" : "bar"}
```

So your

```
for(i in s_array){ alert(typeof(i)); }
```

can be read as

> for each key in the s_array

Answer (score 2):

In js arrays are high-level, list-like objects (associative arrays).

indexes eventually gets coerced into a string by the JavaScript engine, anyway, through an implicit toString conversion.

source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)